# KATALON 5.3.1 version should support UTF8?

Tags: selenium, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, katalon-studio

I use KATALON version 5.3.1. When I load data with String texttomanipulate = data.internallyGetValue where TestData data = findTestData("xxx"). texttomanipulate doesn't show char with accents corectly!
The 5.3.1 version should be UTF8 ?

If yes, there is a bug or something I miss ?
If not, is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

After additional tests:

If data source text with accents (french in my case) come from internal Katalon **variables** -> OK, Data file type **xls** (97-2003 format) -> OK **but** Data file **type CSV -> NOK** (Ok in katalon UI but not at execution

Answer (score 0):

According to [knowledge base](https://docs.katalon.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3179464), Unicode characters are unsupported.

```
Katalon Studio Console mode cannot display Unicode characters due to Windows CMD doesn't support UTF-8 encoding
```

Comment: Katalon studio run java not windows cmd shell ? CMD concern console mode only